# Cannot reference Const.getText before super type constructor has been called in enum

Tags: java

When calling constructor with parameter from default constructor gives error, but calling the getText() method directly from default constructor is working fine.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the order of invocation of constructors.

```java
public enum Const {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2;

    private final String text;

    Const() {
        //this(getText()); --> gives error - Cannot reference Const.getText before super type constructor has been called in enum
        this.text = getText();
    }

    Const(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    private String getText() {
        return "x";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain constructors using this(). It should be the first line of the constructor body.

```
Const() {
this(param1); 
//Rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Wasn't that the code that did not compile (because you cannot call `getText()` before you call the other constructor)?

Comment: right, I was adding this.text = getText(); to indicate that this line was working but not the this(getText()). Modified the question. But that is not the answer to my question.